# Prevent users from running PHP artisan command in Ubuntu

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

I'm currently using the following to manage access rights to my web project folders, which works great:

```
chown -R www-data.www-data ./ && find ./ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; && find ./ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

However, if you are non-sudo user, you can still run the php artisan command, and run somethin like

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

which is not ideal.

Which is the best way to ensure that only `root` can run `php artisan` commands?

Comment: Change the file permissions for the artisan file in the root of the app. note that you can also run artisan commands from the code, so there will always be a way to run the commands. running the commands as root user is not recommended

Comment: You could make use of the command event(s) as described in https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#events with a middleware. I've never done this myself so I can't give you an example. But it is a possible solution to catch any requested command before execution.